# Save 'for loop' values in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL database called ‘locations’ and database table called ‘places’.
My database is as follows

```
----------------------
ID|place|Distance
----------------------
11 |AA | 0
11 |BB | 0
11 |CC | 0
11 |DD | 0
22 |AA | 0
22 |DD | 0
```

I developed a PHP code to find the distance. It is as follows

```
for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
    var dist = parseFloat(route.legs[i].distance.text);
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += 'From<input id="start_address" type="text"  size=10 value="'+route.legs[i].start_address+'">to ';
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<input id="end_address" type="text"  size=10 value="'+route.legs[i].end_address+'">';
    summaryPanel.innerHTML += '=<input id="distance" type="text"  size=10 value="'+dist+'"><br><br>';
```

This works perfectly and the output of this ‘for loop’  is like this.(There is text box called ‘ID’ and it shows an ID number  for this output)

```
ID-1111
From AA to BB = 40
From BB to CC=60
From CC to DD = 20
```

Now I want to do is when clicking on a ‘save’ button, distance column in the database should be updated and saved these distances for the relevant ’ID’ and ‘place’. Final output should be like this.

```
------------------------------
ID  | place | Distance
1111 | AA | 01111 | BB | 40
1111 | CC | 60
1111 | DD | 20
2222 | AA | 0
2222 | DD | 0
```

I tried this thousands times. But the database will not be updated as above. This is what I have tried so far.
Script.js
---------

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var start_address = $("#start_address").val();
        var end_address = $("#end_address").val();
        var distance = $("#distance").val();
        var dataString = 'id1='+ id +'start_address1='+ start_lat + &end_address1='+ end_lat + '&distance1='+ distance;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "map.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                //alert(result);
            }
        });

    }

    return false;

    });

})
```

Map.php

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server..
$db = mysql_select_db("locations", $connection); // Selecting Database
$id2=$_POST['id1'];
$start_address2=$_POST['start_address1'];
$end_address2=$_POST['end_address1'];
$distance2=$_POST['distance1'];

$query=mysql_query("UPDATE places SET distance=’$distance’ WHERE id=’$id2’” && place=’$end_address2’ ");
echo "Updated successfully";
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed

?>
```

Comment: *I developed a PHP code to find the distance. It is as follows* Your PHP code is JS... Also you are using `mysql` which has been officially deprecated.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your PHP code? There is more than one thing wrong with your syntax in the update statement that would cause it to `die()`. Enable the appropriate PHP error levels and add some exception handling to your code. I think you will see the error quite quickly.

Comment: Im fairly sure youre using the wrong accents for SQL. It should be ` not ’.

Comment: You have several syntax errors in Script.js. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: It's missing a quote before `&end_address`, and there's an extra `}` before `return false`

Answer (score 0):

Your query,

```
$query=mysql_query("UPDATE places SET distance=’$distance’ WHERE id=’$id2’” && place=’$end_address2’ ");
```

To,

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE places SET distance='$distance' WHERE id='$id2' AND place='$end_address2'");
```

Notice how you were using backticks instead of single quotes? Also for some reason you closed your query quotes randomly in the middle of the query.

**Edit 1**

Your code is prone to [`SQL injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you are still using `MySQL` even though it has been deprecated, you should use either `MySQLi` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

**Edit 2**

You can also use `or die(mysql_error());` to see what errors are occurring.